# How to compare two different matrices in two different file.mat in octave?

Tags: octave

I need to compare two matrix in two different .mat files, I mean that i have two different files: file1.mat and file2.mat, In each file I have 3 matrix:

File1.mat =(M11, M12, M13)
Fileé.mat =(M21, M22, M23)

I need to compare M11 and M21:

```
function [Matrice_Result]= difference ()

  R1=importdata('file1.mat')
  R2=importdata('file2.mat')

  Matrice_Result= R1== R2
endfunction
```

The error that i found is:

```
error: binary operator '==' not implemented for 'scalar struct' by 'scalar struct' operations
error: called from differences at line 6 column 9
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: is this about matlab or octave? your tags and your title contradict each other

Comment: and your problem seems nothing to do with files, but with `==`; it's not clear what you want to do in that line! Please explain.

Comment: Why not just use `isequal`

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I edit the title, my problem is how to compare juste two matrix in two different files and not  all matrix , I mean that i just need to compare M12 and M21, so how could I point only those two matrix please?

Comment: you compare the matrices instead of the file contents?

Comment: @Suever, I try it, same error. I think that I must precise which matrix to compare however I don't know how to do that?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Yes sir , i need to compare the matrices instead of the file contents, I just need to compare two matrices.

Comment: well, how did you try comparing the different matrices? add that to your question!

Comment: Yes sir, I need to compare them, I already put that, it is my first phrase!

Comment: I did it, could you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest / most appropriate way to load data from a `.mat` file onto the workspace is via the `load` command. It allows you to import only a single variable (whose name you know) into the workspace.

You can do this by simply running the load command, without assigning to a variable:

```
>> load ('file1.mat', 'M11');
>> load ('file2.mat', 'M21');
>> whos
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  ===== 
        M11         1x3                         24  double
        M21         1x3                         24  double

Total is 6 elements using 48 bytes
>> isequal (M11, M21)
ans =  1
```

However, if you *do* collect into a variable, this variable becomes a **struct**, whose fieldnames correspond to the names of the variables you imported, e.g.

```
>> S1 = load ('file1.mat', 'M11');
>> S2 = load ('file2.mat', 'M21');
>> isequal (S1.M11, S2.M21)
ans =  1
```

Comment: @user6652926: I think this answer solves your question. If you still think something is missing comment here.